# Mysql Timestamp Comparison always returns a value

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I have been banging my head against the wall for two days now. I have a simple SQL statement to see if any changes have been made since the last time I looked at the table. No matter what I put for a date range it returns a row. The statement below should return nothing but does return one row. Am I missing something?

```
SELECT date_edit
FROM auctions
WHERE date_edit
BETWEEN '2017-02-13 00:00:00'
AND '2018-02-13 22:00:00'
```

Statement Returns One Row:

```
date_edit   
2016-02-12 09:48:59
```

Thanks in advanced!!

Comment: Is the where clause a typo? Should it be "FROM auctions WHERE date_edit"?

Comment: I think you missed 'Where' from query

SELECT date_edit FROM auctions WHERE date_edit BETWEEN '2017-02-13 00:00:00' AND '2018-02-13 22:00:00'

Comment: A database schema and sample data would help, But, it looks like you are missing a 'WHERE' clause

Comment: It is a typo I do have the where clause. Sorry about that

Comment: Please provide some data of your table **auctions**